# Uploading video to Azure Blob Storage using PUT BLOCK

Tags: ajax, cordova, azure, html5-video, azure-blob-storage

I’m having two problems with Windows Azure Blob Storage.

I’m developing a PhoneGap/Cordova mobile app which records a video, and subsequently uploads the video to Azure Blob Storage using javascript. I’m using a nice javascript recipe from Gaurav Mantri’s blog post: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

Problem 1: The upload process is extremely slow.  I use the PUT BLOCK Api, where a video file is uploaded one block at at time (around 256 KB/file) and eventually the entire file is committed with a PUT BLOCK LIST. A small mp4 video with, e.g., 14 seconds/10 MB will take 5-10 minutes to upload! What happens is that many blocks will be quickly uploaded, and then suddenly the process will pause for several minutes where nothing happens (typically when 40-60% of the blocks are uploaded), and then it will quickly upload another batch of blocks before pausing again.

Here’s a snippet of the javascript I use to upload:

```
  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
  if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
  { 
  var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
  var blockId = blockIdPrefix + pad(blockIds.length, 6);
  blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
  var uri = submitUri + '&comp=block&blockid=' + blockIds[blockIds.length-1];
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      type: "PUT",
      data: requestData,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
          //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
      },
      success: function (data, status) {
        bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
        var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(selectedFile.size)) * 100).toFixed(2);
        console.log(percentComplete + " %");
            uploadFileInBlocks();
              },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(desc);
                console.log(err);
            }
          });
      }
  };


function uploadFileInBlocks() {
    if (totalBytesRemaining > 0) {
        var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
        currentFilePointer += maxBlockSize;
        totalBytesRemaining -= maxBlockSize;
        if (totalBytesRemaining < maxBlockSize) {
            maxBlockSize = totalBytesRemaining;
        }
    } else {
        commitBlockList();
    }
}
```

The storage account is configured to use CORS, and a SAS uri has been generated from Azure management studio (the SAS uri is not generated on the fly as many other examples do). I’ve also tried switching to a locally-redundant storage account besides the Geo-redundant account, but that does not make the upload faster. Unfortunately I cannot trace the traffic with Fiddler or tcpdump, as the code is running on my Android phone.

From the Blob Storage documentation:

"A block blob may be created in one of two ways. Block blobs less than or equal to 64 MB in size can be uploaded by calling the Put Blob operation. Block blobs larger than 64 MB must be uploaded as a set of blocks, each of which must be less than or equal to 4 MB in size. A set of successfully uploaded blocks can be assembled in a specified order into a single contiguous blob by calling Put Block List. The maximum size currently supported for a block blob is 200 GB."

I’m using storage version 2014-02-14 which is specified in the SAS URI: appname.blob.core.windows.net/asset-10146439-dbe1-4af9-85df-a94cf91ef2ec?sr=c&sv=2014-02-14&st=2014-08-13T18%3A01%3A52Z&se=2014-10-18T19%3A01%3A52Z&sp=rwl&sig=mysignature

The reason that I believe the upload can be much faster, is because when I use the PUT BLOB api to upload an, e.g., 10 MB file - it happens very quickly (something like 20-30 secs). However, as the documentation above says, PUT BLOB can only be used for files smaller than 64 MB, which leads to my second problem:

Problem 2: When I use the PUT BLOB api, a Content-Disposition header is inserted into the beginning of the video file, making playback fail (the videos are supposed to be played from an html5 video element). How can I avoid the Content-Disposition header from being automatically inserted when using PUT BLOB? I’ve tried explicitly setting the x-ms-blob-content-disposition to an empty string when uploading, but unfortunately it seems to have no effect (the header is still present).

The code used with PUT BLOB is this:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer(),
options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.httpMethod = "PUT";
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
        ,'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
};

ft.upload(mediaFile.toURL(), submitUri,
    function (e) {
        console.log("upload success!");
    },
    function (e) {
        alert("Upload failed");
    }, options);
```

I've also tried a third approach, which is to upload the file using XMLHttpRequest, this results in a file without the Content-Disposition header, but the video file is somehow broken - it cannot be played back, not even when downloading it to the desktop (I've opened the video file in a hex editor, and the beginning bytes of the file looks exactly like the bytes from a valid mp4 file... maybe someone fluent in the mp4 format can figure out what the problem is, here's is an example of such a broken video file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B3105327829B3E0C!23617&authkey=!AHoS6cZJmDlIN-E&ithint=file%2cmp4

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var rawData = null;

 try {
reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (evt) {
    rawData = reader.result;
    ajaxRequest.open('PUT', submitUri, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
    ajaxRequest.send(rawData);
    console.log("done uploading!")    
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For #1, can you please trace the request through Fiddler or something like that and see if anything special is happening when the code is stuck. For #2, can you please share the code? Content disposition header is optional and should not be there if you're not specifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Guarav! And especially the article you posted with the original code! I updated the question with more info. I can't really run Fiddler as the code is running on a phone.

Comment: hi... can you please share what solved your problem? I am facing a similar issue with my iphone app. Thanks in advance.